# Removing text and only showing a portion of the answer

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to run an index match that returns some text, but I don't want the full text, just the portion that varies within the set. For example, cell A1 would contain...

```
[I want to better understand what you did during this visit] During this visit, did the you... (select appropriate answer) [Receive a tour]
```

A2...

```
[I want to better understand what you did during this visit] During this visit, did the you... (select appropriate answer) [Meet with the manager]
```

How would you extract it to just say...

```
A1               A2
Receive a tour   Meet with the manager
```

The text can vary a lot, sometimes it'll have a second set of square brackets, sometimes not. But one consistency within Google Form data is that the last pair of square brackets is that part that contains the answer that varies. I'd like to get just this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...is that the last pair of square brackets is that part that contains the answer that varies. I'd like to get just this text

try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "([^\[]*)\]$")))
```

[image: 0]

or more blunt:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\s\[(.*)\]$")))
```

[image: 0]